# What is the Best Way to Limit Redirection to the Success Page after a PayPal Donation

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, paypal

We have a donation button on our web site that goes to PayPal.  The donation gets processed, the user clicks a button on the PayPal success page and is then redirected back to a PHP page with a list of maps to download.  I want to limit who can access this page to users coming from PayPal or users coming from our site.  I have tried various .htaccess rules and they don't seem to work with users coming from PayPal http_referrer wise.  And the referring IP always ends up being my IP address at home.  I also tried coding the PHP redirect target form such that it with only renders the page if they are coming from paypal.com or from our site.  Otherwise, they get an error page.  So can anyone please suggest a better way to restrict access to the redirect page after the PayPal success page?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about it. This is something I have used in the past.

Firstly, you want to give access to users who have made a payment (or donated). Depending on whether you want to give users (who have paid) a one time access or allow multiple visits even after they log out, you can check whether this user, in this session, made a payment or not.

Here's one way to achieve it:

```
    // PAYMENT CONFIRMATION 
$payment_success="FALSE"; // DEFAULT to payment failed
$payment=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['payment']);
$ab=$_REQUEST['ab'];
$tx=$_REQUEST['tx'];
$st=$_REQUEST['st'];
$amt=$_REQUEST['amt'];

if(($tx!="") AND ($st=="Completed") AND ($amt!="")){
    $payment_success="TRUE";
}else{
    header("location: index.php"); // or wherever you want to send users who haven't paid.
}
```

If you want to give access to users who have paid even after they have logged out, then you need to either set a cookie on their browser using [`setcookie();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) or track their IP `[$_SERVER\['REMOTE_ADDR'\]][2]`and add to your DB so every time a user comes to your page, you can run a check to see if they are in your safe list or not.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding a static token to the end of the PayPal redirect URL back to my site.  I test the token within the target PHP page and let them access the target maps page if the token is correct.  And I give them an error screen if it is not.  This is a short term fix as I will have to manually change the token every now and then to keep people from bookmarking the page and downloading our maps more than once.

I'm going to experiment with either generating random buttons with different tokens or seeing if PayPal has something that they can send from their end that I can verify.

Thanks for the reply.